# Disproving a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Q = \{f \in C[1,3]:f(2)=4\}$. Show that S is not a vector space.

Cant figure out which axiom Q fails.

Comment: Does the zero function belong to $Q$?

Comment: It isn't closed under scalar multiplication or addition.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The zero element of $C[1,3]$ is the function $0 \colon [1,3] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $0[t]=0$ for all $t \in [1,3]$. But $0 \notin Q$ since otherwise $0(2)=4$. Therefore the zero vector cannot belong to $Q$, which therefore cannot be a subspace.